# FragmentManager from Context

Tags: android

I created a new `View` class.  Within that class I need to get access to the `FragmentManager`, but I cannot figure out how.

Can I access the `FragmentManager` from a context?

```
CustomView extends LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Only if the given Context extends Activity (Post-Honeycomb) or FragmentActivity (pre-honeycomb).

In which case you'd have to make 100% sure it's an activity using reflection or try-catch.

```
try{
  final Activity activity = (Activity) context;

  // Return the fragment manager
  return activity.getFragmentManager();

  // If using the Support lib.
  // return activity.getSupportFragmentManager(); 

} catch (ClassCastException e) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Can't get the fragment manager with this");
}
```

Thought I recommend refactoring so a `View` is really just meant for showing stuff and shouldn't actually modify the state of your app, but that's my opinion.

Comment: A DialogFragment contains the view in question.  I basically have a DialogFragment that is divided into sections based on the button currently selected I show the appropriate view.  I divided each displayable section into it's own view.  I would have used a Fragment, but I can't embed a fragment within a fragment.

Comment: I'm just going to find the view by id, and pass in a reference to the Activity.

Comment: Why not just have the DialogFragment handle view swapping?  It seems like it would be just as complicated as what you're trying to do.

Comment: That is what it is doing.  The DialogFragment is swapping the views.  However, I have the views containing some logic, and possibly displaying other dialog fragments in response to use events, so the views need a way to get the fragment manager.  I know it's not recommended to have views contain logic..I'm just not sure a better way to divide the sections.

Comment: What if it extends to Fragment?

Comment: @LeiLeyba: Fragments have a "getFragmentManager()" and "getChildFragmentManager()" methods, so I'm not sure what you're asking.  Those will (probably) return null if the Fragment isn't attached to an Activity though.  You can also use "getActivity().getFragmentManager()" to get the FragmentManager used as well.

Comment: "In which case you'd have to make 100% sure it's an activity using reflection or try-catch." Or just using the instanceof operator is even better.

Comment: Just a heads-up for anyone looking at this after 2019, after Android 28 Activity::getFragmentManager() is deprecated. You need to use as described in @clocksmith 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24915799/2670002).

Answer (score 50):

if you are using support fragments, you probably actually want:

```
try {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
  Log.e(TAG, "Can't get fragment manager");
}
```

Comment: val fragmentManager = (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager  in kotlin

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

```
Context mContext;
...


//Get FragmentManager
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
```

(Of course you have to first of all initialize mContext)

Comment: what is this logic of casting, how it made possible

Answer (score 4):

Since your context object can't always be directly casted to Activity, this is a more reliable way to do this:

```
@Nullable
public static Activity getActivityFromContext(@NonNull Context context){
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
        if (context instanceof Activity) return (Activity) context;
        context = ((ContextWrapper)context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null; //we failed miserably 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get access to a FragmentManager (or SupportFragmentManager) in an Application - but as other answers suggests, you can only do this via an Activity instance.

However, you can gain access to a FragmentManager via an Activity without needing to directly call any Activities using the ActivityLifecycleCallbacks interface:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        activity.getFragmentManager()
        if(activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            ((FragmentActivity)activity).getSupportFragmentManager();
        }
        unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    ...
```