# Need advice in using Fragment Manager inside Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout, fragmentmanager

I have a question about using Fragment Manager inside Relative Layout and I have tried a lot of different codes that I have found here but non of them help me. I've create a list of question that get out of my Data Base and I can get transfer from this list to second page with full explanation from my DB. 
in my code getFragmentManager lights in red.
Can any one help me to figure it out and solve this issue?

```
public class RuleButton extends RelativeLayout {
    private TextView namerul;
    private String nameRule = "";

    public RuleButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initComponent();
    }

    public  void initComponent() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.rulesbutton, this);
         namerul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ruleName);
        namerul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFullRule();
            }
        });
        updateFields();
    }

    public void setRuleName(String name) {
        nameRule = name;
        namerul.setText(nameRule);
    }

    public void updateFields() {
        setRuleName(nameRule);

    }

    public void getFullRule () {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("Rule",nameRule);
        fragment = new SomeRuleFragment();

        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        }
        else { // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment"); }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My resolution was to pass Fragment Manager in Constructor:

```
    public RuleButton(Context context, FragmentManager _fragmentManager, boolean s) {
    super(context);
    fragmentManager = _fragmentManager;
    initComponent(s);
}

public void getFullRule () {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("Rule", ruleID);
    fragment = new SomeRuleFragment();

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("")
                .commit();
    }
    else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your class extends RelativeLayout
RelativeLayout does't have getFragmentManager
pass activity to your class and try `activity.getFragmentManager`
check this out: [FragmentManager from Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689997/fragmentmanager-from-context)

Comment: I don't actually get what exactly I need to do. I have tryed to make it this way
     <code>   if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            Activity mainAct = new MainActivity();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = mainAct.getFragmentManager();  <code>

but still there is no luck. apk doesn't work and fall when I'm trying to get new fragment