# getFragmentManager gets the null value while trying to fetch value from a method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a method in PlaceDetailsActivity.java given below:

```
 public void implementFragment()
    {
        TestFrag testingFragmentFragment = new TestFrag();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map_fragment, testingFragmentFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

If I try to access this method of PlaceDetailsActivity.java from DetailsInfoActivity.java like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          PlaceDetailsActivity placeDetailsActivity= new PlaceDetailsActivity();
          placeDetailsActivity.implementFragment();
         finish();
        }
    });
```

I get null value here `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();`
But if I call it from PlaceDetailsActivity's onCreate then it works properly. Here TestFrag is a Fragment class. My question is what to do 
now if I want to call implementFragment() method of PlaceDetailsActivity.java from DetailsInfoActivity.java without getting  null value?

Comment: show your code to get more idea on it.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: I have tried this but get the null again [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689997/fragmentmanager-from-context?newreg=044a4990d9414c2cac9c106600a9e180]

Comment: NEVER create an Activity with new. Lets do this the Android System.

Comment: I haven't created but I called the Activity, initialize it.

Comment: For sure, your have created it: PlaceDetailsActivity placeDetailsActivity= new PlaceDetailsActivity();

Comment: Then how can I call a method of another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `getFragmentManager()` use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Here getFragmentManager() is ok. When I call the method from same Oncreate() then it does not show any null value. But It shows null value only when the method is called from different Activity. What can I do in that case?

Comment: You cannot call implementFragment before onCreate happens. Use startActivity and put the implementFragment in the onCreate of the activity which will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following one. I assume your previous code is placed inside the PlaceDetailsActivity class.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     implementFragment();
     finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I want it in such way that I have a button in DetailsInfoActivity.java and If I click the button It calls the method(implementFragment()) in  PlaceDetailsActivity.java and it Starts Fragment(TestFragment.java). But during Fragment I got null value in getFragmentManager(). How can I solve it? getFragmentManager() is not null if I call it from its onCreate() of PlaceDetailsActivity.java