# Call fragment From recyclerView adapter

Tags: android, fragment

I want call fragment on `imageItem` click
`getSupportFragmentManger` cannot call hera and when pass it in adapter constructor also cannot work

```java
   public class MarketOneRecyclerAdapter extends       RecyclerView.Adapter<MarketOneRecyclerAdapter.MainViewHolder>{                                          
                                                                                                                                                      
       public interface OnItemClickListener {                                                                                                            
           void onItemClick(ArrayList< MarketItems> item, int Pos);                                                                                      
       }                                                                                                                                                 
       private final OnItemClickListener listener;                                                                                                       
       private ArrayList<MarketItems>marketArrayList;                                                                                                    
       private Context context;                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                      
         public MarketOneRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MarketItems> marketArrayList,  OnItemClickListener listener) {                         
        this.listener = listener;                                                                                                                     
        this.context = context;                                                                                                                       
        this.marketArrayList = marketArrayList;                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                 
    @Override                                                                                                                                         
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {                                                                        
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())                                                                                          
                .inflate(R.layout.market_item, parent, false);                                                                                        
        return new MarketOneRecyclerAdapter.MainViewHolder(view);                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                      
    @Override                                                                                                                                         
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, int position) {                                                                               
        holder.bind(marketArrayList,listener,position);                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                      
    @Override                                                                                                                                         
    public int getItemCount() {                                                                                                                       
        return marketArrayList.size();                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                 

                                                                                                                                             
    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
        ImageView imageItem;                                                                                                                          
        CardView cardView;                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
        public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                      
            super(itemView);                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
            cardView= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_card_view);                                                                        
            imageItem= (ImageView)      itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_item_imageView);                                                                 
            imageItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                                                                 
                @Override                                                                                                                             
                public void onClick(View view) {                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
                    //Want here call a fragment                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                      
                }                                                                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                             
        public void bind(final ArrayList<MarketItems> item, final OnItemClickListener listener , final int i){                                        
                            Picasso.with(context).load(marketArrayList.get(i).getImages()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageItem);                      
                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                      
            imageItem.setTag(item.get(i).getImages());                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                      
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                                                                  
                @Override                                                                                                                             
                public void onClick(View view) {                                                                                                      
                    listener.onItemClick(item,i);                                                                                                     
            `enter code here`       }                                                                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                                                       
        }                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                 
}     

public  class ImageItemFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_item, container, false);

        imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.market_item_image);
        //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(marketItems.getImages()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageView);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: See the accepted answer to this post:
[getting FragmentManager from Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689997/fragmentmanager-from-context)

Comment: build public void from your activity to call a fragment, then used in adapter `((YourActivity)context).callFragmentMethod()`

Comment: or you can post how you call fragment from an activity?

Comment: cannot call the fragment also in the activity... i create recyclerView item click listener and call the fragment donot work

Comment: please show how you call the fragment? i didint see it?

Comment: using that to call the fragment from activity  ...public void callFragment(){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_market_one, new ImageItemFragment())
                .commit();
    }

Comment: please post your ImageItemFragment

Comment: that the fragment but i donot handel yet ...public  class ImageItemFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_item, container, false);

        imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.market_item_image);
        //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(marketItems.getImages()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageView);


        return view;
    }
}

Comment: edited my post with this fragment

Comment: is there any log error shown?

Comment: on event when click to call the fragment...sorry bad english

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer and indent everything 4 more spaces to get all the code in the code block, or cut/paste it into an editor, use block indent and copy/paste it back, if selecting it and then doing command-K doesn't fix it in Stack Overflow editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

holder is ViewHolder inOnBindViewHolder

```
holder.image_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
            Fragment myFragment = new TaskApprovalFragmentDetails();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.linearlayouttaskapproval, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();


        }
    });
```

Comment: This is such a bad idea and here is why. Holder should not make any actions on it's own. In your case you don't have control over what is going on on click. You should set the listener to any action happening inside holder and handle it outside of adapter (in fragment/activity/view). Just pass the listener(s) to the adapter and then pass it to the holder in `onCreateViewHolder()`. This way you will have control over the business logic and SOLID principles will be respected

Comment: @AlexGrebennikov Holder can take actions on it's view there is nothing wrong in that. Using interface is always a good idea but i don't see any performance and leak issues here. If you do please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin you can use this

```
holder.setOnClickListener{it:View!
     val appCompatActivity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
                    appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.
                    beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frameLayout, YourFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit()
      }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the developer confuse during call the Fragment but i have two way to move from Recycler adapter to Fragment.
To move from recycler adapter to fragment we need Fragment name, and Fragment support manager Library and then we will use the method like add, replace etc.
so if you have two way :
if you are using direct POJO class based Fragment then use can use

```
Youractivity.viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

like in my

```
MainActivity.viewPager2.setCurrentItem(0);
```

here 0 is my Fragment position.
Suppose if you are using Fragment as per android documentation then we will use:

```
                    FragmentManager manager = ((AppCompatActivity)mcontext).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,tab1)
                            .commit();
```

Here Tab1 is my fragment name and i create an instance for my Fragment and R.id.container is my container id. Most of developer dont know how to get container id, so there are many way but the easiest way is that, go to your fragment and check your onCreateView in fragment , there are something like this:

```
  View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.community,container,false);
```

Hope this will work for you, If you have some issue then comment me. Enjoy !!!

Comment: Wow , Thanks alot sir, People here confuse developers. they write a less amount of code. You clear my all concept. Actually i'm using POJO class based Fragment. Add and replace type Fragment is too much old now.

Comment: Thanks alot ma'am

Comment: Sir, can you tell me if i use a method to find out fragment id, so how to programatically it replace to all the movements

Comment: By create a public class or by using Persistence storage you can call. Bundle is typical process if you using. it will helpful Fragment to fragment. Or you can directly call the object from your pojo class

Comment: I think to call pojo class is best method